# Regular Expression to match only nonescaped string

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I've been bashing my head against this one for a while now. I have need of a regex to match a string only if it is not escaped. For example, this regex needs to match `<string>` and `\\<string>`, but not `\<string>`, as well as any arbitrary number of escapes before it (so, match even number of escapes, but not odd number).

Ideally, it wouldn't matter as all what  was, so that this wonderful little regex tidbit I'm looking for could be used by anyone to be slapped in front of any expression to only return properly non-escaped strings. This regex must function in PHP.

Theoretically, this should work for the first two levels of escape, but it doesn't:

```
(?<!\\(?<!\\\\))
```

And besides, that method would have to be extremely large to handle every possible length of escape characters.

More specifically, I'm using this regex in a preg_replace(). This is being done to decolorize quake3 Arena player aliases, using another tidbit of regex to match the colorization string. Basically, I'm looking for a regex that will match `^<alphanumeric-char>` and `\\^<alphanumeric-char>`, but not `\^<alphanumeric-char>`.

An example:

```
$find = "^3Foo^7bAR\^7kicks\\^bass";

$string = preg_replace('<regex>', '', $find);
```

Should return `$string = "Foobar\^7kicks\ass"`.

Comment: How are you using this regular expression? preg_match_all? preg_replace? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: You need to surround the pattern with delimiters (conventionally `/`) so that you add modifiers after the second delimiter.

Comment: Shouldn’t it rather be `FoobAR\^7kicksbass`?

Comment: @Dakota: No wait. It should rather be `FoobAR\^7kicks\^bass` as `"\\"` evaluates to a single `\‍`.

Comment: Fixed... it should actually evaluate \\^b to just \, since that is what quake3 arena does when it colorizes from those tags.

Comment: @Dakota: Ok, now I’m totally confused. ;)

Comment: @Gumbo: Well, quake3 arena looks at the \\ and turns it into \ and then ignores it (because it just messed with it) and moves on to the `^x` and sees it as a clean colorization marker. It keeps things from going in a loop removing \'s and allows players to show a `\foo` and have the `foo` part be colorized. Care to hop in chat under PHP and remove this horrible delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<string>~'
```

Short and concise.

Comment: Closest one yet! I'll just have to run over the strings again and clean out the //'s.